# Any Differences between -n and ! -z condition in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Is there any differences between the following two codes?
I have got the desired result from the first one, however,
the second code can not check the end of string. (Ubuntu 22.04).
Any Comments would be great thanks!

```
#-----
#!/bin/bash
i=1
a=$(echo $PATH | cut -d ':' -f $i)
while [ ! -z $a ]
do
    echo $a
    ((i++))
    a=$(echo $PATH | cut -d ':' -f $i)
done
#-----
i=1
a=$(echo $PATH | cut -d ':' -f $i)
while [ -n $a ]
do
    echo $a
    ((i++))
    a=$(echo $PATH | cut -d ':' -f $i)
done
```

Comment: Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: [And shellcheck is here](https://www.shellcheck.net/).